# creating a picture with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I create a picture like this with TikZ?

[image]

Comment: Have you already started with some code lines? You will have more success if you help us to help you, so that we do not have to start from scratch.

Comment: Here you can find a similar example: Table in the shape of an arrow: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/arrow-table/